# AWS Lambda: "Cannot read property '0' of undefined"

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

Here is my AWS Lambda function. However, when running it, I get `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const SES = new AWS.SES();

const FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS = process.env.FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS;
const TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS = process.env.TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS;

function sendEmailToMe(formData) {

    const emailParams = {
        Source: FROM_EMAIL_ADDRESS, 
        ReplyToAddresses: ['keshijemi478@gmail.com'],
        Destination: {
          ToAddresses: [TO_EMAIL_ADDRESS], 
        },
        Message: {
          Body: {
            Text: {
              Charset: 'UTF-8',
              Data: `Thanks for subscribe: ${formData.message}\n\n Name: ${formData.name}\n Email: ${formData.email}\n I will reply as soon as possible`,
            },
          },
          Subject: {
            Charset: 'UTF-8',
            Data: 'New message from your_site.com',
          },
        },
    };

    console.log(emailParams);

    const promise =  SES.sendEmail(emailParams).promise();
    console.log(promise);
    return promise;
}


exports.handler = async(event) => {
    console.log('SendEmail called');

  
   const dynamodb = event.Records[0].dynamodb;
    console.log(dynamodb);

    const formData = {
        name : dynamodb.NewImage.name.S,
        message : dynamodb.NewImage.message.S,
        email : dynamodb.NewImage.email.S
    };
    console.log(formData);

    return sendEmailToMe(formData).then(data => {
        console.log(data);
    }).catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

Comment: You triggered the event manually, didn't you?

Comment: Yeah ,mmm  i did

Comment: Because of that, your `event` does not contain any `Records` yet, so `event.Records[0]` will result in an `undefined`. You should try stubbing the event payload, which contains `Records` when triggering the event.

Comment: I didn't Understand.............

Comment: How can i solve this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that your code is an AWS Lambda function.

When a Lambda function is called, information is passed to the function via the `event` parameter. The information passed via `event` varies depending upon *how* the function was triggered. For example, if the function is triggered by an Amazon S3 Event, then S3 provides information in the `event` parameter that describes the object that caused the event to be triggered.

If, however, you trigger this event 'manually', then Amazon S3 is not involved and the `event` parameter only contains the information that you provided when *you* invoked the function.

If you are testing the function in the AWS Lambda management console, you can supply an `event` via the "Configure Test" option. The event provided in this configuration will then be passed to the function being tested.

Comment: I did supply event via the Configure Test .But another error came...Cannot read property 'S' of undefined

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html